# Is moving plants around good for plants?

Tags: plant-health, plant-care

I am new to gardening. My neighbour owns a garden and has a lot of plants in pots. I see him regularly moving those pots around the garden, some pots in the interval of 2-3 days, others in 2-3 weeks. Also he changes those pots sometimes.

Is this good for plants? Should I do the same with my plants also(i.e. changing their places)?

Comment: Are your own plants in pots as well, or in the ground, in other words, are you asking if you should dig up and move your plants rather than  just moving pots around?

Comment: I have several plants in pots. I am asking whether I should change the places of those pots. Does that help plants in any way?

Comment: Maybe you can ask him/her. Maybe it is just for planing (test composition). Or maybe it is just for doing something. Or maybe s/he is a photographer and so he want different backgrounds. I think only your neighbor can answer, and you can expect a surprising answers (and we are curious).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People might move plant pots around for various reasons, though quite why they would need to be moved every 2 or 3 days as you observe your neighbour doing is a bit of a mystery.

They may be rotated to allow for more light exposure to promote even growth all round, especially if they are up against a wall or fence; they may be moved to a sunnier position at various times, or a shadier one if its hot and dry;they may be moved to create a more aesthetic display for the owner, or some pots may be moved further forward because whatever is in the pot is currently in flower, with those finished flowering moved elsewhere.

There are really only two reasons that could be said to be beneficial; one is to increase light levels at certain times, if that's necessary and two,to move a pot to a more sheltered position, perhaps in winter or if the weather is very windy, otherwise, it's more likely for aesthetic reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Don't think changing pot positions will benefit the plants. Ofcourse if the sunlight is not uniform or the space is sheltered, rotating pots will be beneficial to the plants. Although, it is advisable to change the compost/soil in a pot every 2 to 3 years. Although you can change the pots positions for aesthetic affects or just not to be bored.